# Working with decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I have a javascript function that converts feet into a usable object that will take the total feet and break it down into feet / inch / fraction.

In the example below the decimal fraction portion should be zero and my inch should be 4

Lets say I've got the following.

```
var inches = 40;
```

Now when I call the function below like so unPackDecimalFeet(40 /12);

```
  unPackDecimalFeet: function (feetInchFraction) {

        var inchFraction = (feetInchFraction - ~~feetInchFraction) * 12;
        return {
            feet: ~~feetInchFraction,
            inch: ~~inchFraction,
            fraction: inchFraction - ~~inchFraction
        };
    }
```

My return value is below.

```
feet: 3
fraction: 0.9999999999999964
inch: 3
```

**The above return value should read.

```
feet: 3
fraction: 0
inch: 4
```

How would I need to process the feet so that I can get the correct return value?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say multiply it by `1000` in the beginning, then do your calculations, and then divide by `1000`. IEEE Floating Point arithmetic is the problem here. If you need more calculations, look into BigInteger libraries. (BigInt, sometimes)

Comment: Can you please give me a break down.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inchesIn;
inchesIn = 40;
document.writeln('Feet: ' + Math.floor(inchesIn/12));
document.writeln('Inches: ' + inchesIn%12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot to try and save yourself from tiny little inconsequential fraction issues throughout your code. I think maybe simpler is better:

```
unPackDecimalFeet : (function (feet) {
    var flooredFeet = 0 | feet,
        flooredInches = 0 | ((feet - flooredFeet) * 12),
        inchFraction = (feet * 12) - (0 | (feet * 12));

    return {
        feet: flooredFeet,
        inch: flooredInches,
        fraction: +(inchFraction.toFixed(2)) //Rounded to two decimals
    };
})
```

The only "trickiness" there is with `0 |` as an alternative to `Math.floor()`. Feel free to use `Math.floor()` if it makes you feel better about maintainability. Also, I rounded off the "fraction" part of the response to the nearest 100th of an inch. You can round more precisely if you want, but some rounding is encouraged to prevent things like `0.9999999999999994` or whatever due to IEEE-754 gone wild.